# Should I use emq+emq-web-hook to persist messages to database?

Tags: emq

My idea is use the emq broker + emq-web-hook sending all published messages to NodeJS API that only will be send to RabbitMQ (balance) and I instantiate some applications to consume. Should this work?

Comment: Sorry but is there a specific question here?

Comment: I would like to know the opnion of the people about it

Comment: @JoseCarlosPineli asking for opinion isn't really a good fit for this site.  I've tried to clear up your question a bit, but please feel free to [edit] to make the question more concrete.  See [How to ask](https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/asking) for more information.